# Installing gtk development environment

Tags: programming, gtk, application-development

Not new to Ubuntu or programming but I am new to programming in C and gtk. Have been using Quickly for the odd program. I want to play around with C and gtk.

What gtk packages do I need to install to have a working development environment with C?

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ was also very helpful to me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I cheat and use the list of packages needed to build other big GTK applications instead:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep inkscape
```

Or for a more minimal starting point, go with the bare minimum and add on when you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: nice one. Thanks for this info(apt-get build)

Comment: For GTK3 development it is needed to install libgtk-3-dev package.

Answer (score 17):

For a full development environment, the [gnome-devel](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-devel) [image: Install gnome-devel] metapackage will install a full GTK + GNOME development environment, including the development documentation and the Anjuta IDE.

This is quite a lot more than the minimal set of things you'll need for GTK development, but it can be nice to have everything you're likely to need available.

Comment: THIS. I've been trying to get a library working and it kept complaining about missing dependencies and I got it to work in a couple of minutes with this.

Comment: @RAOF: gnome-devel doesn't install on Ubuntu 14.04. Error: http://pastebin.com/QJXzpVmN Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an application like Anjuta or CodeBlocks (both can be found in the software center).

I would HIGHLY suggest Anjuta over most other IDE's for it's Glade integration (among other features), usage of autotools (less headaches), and the portability of the code (you can use any text editor you like =).

If you have no idealogical issues, you can try using Monodevelop (it's a good IDE, similar to Visual Studio).

To get the dependencies for a basic GTK+ development, just install buildessential and libgtk2.0-dev as Kees noted.