# Do I need to know C++ to develop Ubuntu apps?

Tags: application-development, c++, qml, javascript

I'm a java developer. I don't know much about C++. should I learn C++ to develop Ubuntu apps?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have a look at the "Getting started" section of the http://developer.ubuntu.com/ site. It would also be very useful if you could include what kind of app you're trying to develop. Command-line tool, Twitter app, etc.

Comment: Here's a related question: [How do I get started creating an Ubuntu Desktop App?](http://askubuntu.com/q/49849/88802) suggests Quickly (uses Python).

Comment: You say you are a Java developer but you have a tag Javascript. Javascript and Java are not the same, did you know?

Comment: @gertvdjik : It is outdated, quickly is no longer recommended

Comment: @com.BOY : BTW qml(the recommended language) is a javascript plugin

Comment: @Tachyons Interesting, but I was just pointing at the fact that Java and Javascript are two totally different languages.

Answer (score 6):

No. You can also use Java, Python, C, Javascript, QML, Vala, and C#, and probably other languages too.

[image]

[Source (archived)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140219202836/http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/documentation/platform-diagram/)

Comment: It would be nice if you could link your answer to some relevant source.

Comment: @saji89 Have one now

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to learn C++ to write apps for Ubuntu.

Ubuntu apps are based on the Ubuntu SDK, with which you'll be programming in QML and JavaScript for some of the logic. There is the possibility to use C++ if your application does any operations that require maximum performance (e.g. advanced image processing), but for most apps QML should be enough.

The Get Started page on developer.ubuntu.com should give you all the information you need. [Check it out](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/).