# How to develop Ubuntu apps (2013 edition)

Tags: application-development, python

I know this question has come up before, but the answers can quickly go out of date. No pun intended. ;) Previously, it was the "quickly" tool to build apps. Now, developer.ubuntu.com points you to the ubuntu-sdk package. My question is, can I develop desktop apps with this? It seems to be geared towards mobile touch apps. I want to be able to develop GUI apps in Python.

Comment: Do I have to be an app developer in order to get the pun? ):

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/335454/109543).